# ¿Cómo unir dos códigos php en uno solo?

Tags: php

Tengo un código que funciona para guardar los valores de los `checkbox` en mi base de datos y otro que sirve para guardar lo que los usuarios escriben en ciertos campos, el problema es que cuando intento unirlos me manda como 12 errores, y quiero saber como unirlos en un solo código PHP.

Este es el código que intente mezclar:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert']) && isset($_POST['insert1']) && 
   isset($_POST['insert2']) && isset($_POST['insert3']) && 
   isset($_POST['insert4']) && isset($_POST['insert5']) && 
   isset($_POST['insert6']))
{
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","datos3");
$sql= "INSERT INTO other_fields(Teachers_Name, School_Name, 
       Implementation_Quality, Number_of_Teachers, 
       Number_of_Trained_Teachers, BOOKS, CONCRETS, TRAININGS, CURRICULUM, 
       CLASS_OBSERVATIONS, INTERVENTIONS, TESTING) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, 
       ?,'".$_POST["insert"]."', '".$_POST["insert1"]."', 
       '".$_POST["insert2"]."', '".$_POST["insert3"]."', 
       '".$_POST["insert4"]."', '".$_POST["insert5"]."', 
       '".$_POST["insert6"]."')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo "Data Inserted Succesfully";
}
?>
```

Estos son los errores que muestra:

> Notice: Undefined index: Teachers_Name in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined index: School_Name in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 20
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Implementation_Quality in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 24
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Number_of_Teachers in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Number_of_Trained_Teachers in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 32
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 45
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 46
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 47
>   Hubo algun error

Acá esta el código para los `checkboxs`

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['insert']) && isset($_POST['insert1']) && 
   isset($_POST['insert2']) && isset($_POST['insert3']) && 
   isset($_POST['insert4']) && isset($_POST['insert5']) && 
   isset($_POST['insert6']))
{
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","datos3");
$query= "INSERT INTO other_fields(BOOKS, CONCRETS, TRAININGS, CURRICULUM, 
         CLASS_OBSERVATIONS, INTERVENTIONS, TESTING) 
         VALUES('".$_POST["insert"]."', '".$_POST["insert1"]."', 
         '".$_POST["insert2"]."', '".$_POST["insert3"]."', 
         '".$_POST["insert4"]."', '".$_POST["insert5"]."', 
         '".$_POST["insert6"]."')";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo "Data Inserted Succesfully";
}
?>
```

Este es el otros(en el que guarda lo escrito por el usuario)

```
<?php

$Teachers_Name="";
$Teachers_Name= isset($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
$Teachers_Name= empty($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
$Teachers_Name= $_POST['Teachers_Name'] ?? '';
$School_Name="";
$School_Name= isset($_POST['School_Name']) ? $_POST['School_Name']:'';
$School_Name= empty($_POST['School_Name']) ? $_POST['School_Name']:'';
$School_Name= $_POST['School_Name'] ?? '';
$Implementation_Quality= "";
$Implementation_Quality= isset($_POST['Implementation_Quality']) ? 
 $_POST['Implementation_Quality']:'';
$Implementation_Quality= empty($_POST['Implementation_Quality']) ? 
 $_POST['Implementation_Quality']:'';
$Implementation_Quality= $_POST['Implementation_Quality'] ?? '';
$Number_of_Teachers= "";
$Number_of_Teachers= isset($_POST['Number_of_Teachers']) ? 
 $_POST['Number_of_Teachers']:'';
$Number_of_Teachers= empty($_POST['Number_of_Teachers']) ? 
 $_POST['Number_of_Teachers']:'';
$Number_of_Teachers= $_POST['Number_of_Teachers'] ?? '';
$Number_of_Trained_Teachers= "";
$Number_of_Trained_Teachers= isset($_POST['Number_of_Trained_Teachers']) ? 
 $_POST['Number_of_Trained_Teachers']:'';
$Number_of_Trained_Teachers= empty($_POST['Number_of_Trained_Teachers']) ? 
 $_POST['Number_of_Trained_Teachers']:'';
$Number_of_Trained_Teachers= $_POST['Number_of_Trained_Teachers'] ?? '';
//Guarda las variables


$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","datos3");
$sql= "INSERT INTO datos_4(Teachers_Name, School_Name, 
       Implementation_Quality, Number_of_Teachers, 
       Number_of_Trained_Teachers) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)";

$sth = mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'ssssssssssss', $Teachers_Name, $School_Name, 
                       $Implementation_Quality, $Number_of_Teachers, 
                       $Number_of_Trained_Teachers);
$ejecutar = mysqli_stmt_execute($sth);

if(!$ejecutar){
 echo "Hubo algun error";
} else {

 echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='index.php'>Volver</a>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Seria genial que muestres el mensaje de los 12 errores.

Comment: OK, ya lo edito

Comment: Gracias por editar mi código @Xerif

Comment: De hecho lo mejor es que lo mantengas separado en archivos porque ambos realizan acciones con diferentes valores de POST, y al querer ejecutar todo el código, no todos tus índices de POST que usas en ambos archivos están inicializados, por lo que te manda esos errores

Comment: @Yikarus Es que o que necesito es guardar todos esos datos en una sola fila en mi base de datos, y pues no sé aún como hacerlo

Comment: Quieres guardarlos en una sola fila pero estás insertando en dos tablas distintas, cómo es eso?

Answer (score 0):

Ok veamos si entiendo.

**Primero**, en tu script final tienes cosas como esta:

```
$Teachers_Name="";
$Teachers_Name= isset($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
$Teachers_Name= empty($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
$Teachers_Name= $_POST['Teachers_Name'] ?? '';
```

La manera correcta de setear la variable `$Teachers_Name` es simplemente la segunda línea

```
$Teachers_Name= isset($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
```

Imagínate que `$_POST['Teachers_Name']` no viene en el request. Eso hará que en la tercera y cuarta línea intentes usar esa llave sin que esté seteada, lo cual dará lugar al error:

> Notice: Undefined index: Teachers_Name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 16

Que significa que `$_POST` no tiene una llave `Teachers_Name`

**Segundo**: en tu consulta de inserción los valores tienen un error de sintaxis:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO datos_4(Teachers_Name, School_Name, 
       Implementation_Quality, Number_of_Teachers, 
       Number_of_Trained_Teachers) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)";
```

Los placeholders para cinco campos debieran ser `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` y no `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)` (sobra una coma).

Eso provoca que al preparar la sentencia

```
$sth = mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql);
```

El valor de `$sth` no sea un `mysqli_stmt` válido sino el booleano `false`, y por tanto no es apto como argumento para `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` ni para `mysqli_stmt_execute` y tira los errores

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 46

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\insert.php on line 47
```

**Tercero**: estás intendando hacer `bind` de **doce** strings `ssssssssssss` y pasándole sólo **cinco** parámetros:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'ssssssssssss', 
    $Teachers_Name,  // parámetro 1
    $School_Name,  // parámetro 2
    $Implementation_Quality,  // parámetro 3
    $Number_of_Teachers, // parámetro 4
    $Number_of_Trained_Teachers // parámetro 5
    );
```

Ahora, tomándome de la inserción que pareciera quieres hacer:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO other_fields(Teachers_Name, School_Name, 
   Implementation_Quality, Number_of_Teachers, 
   Number_of_Trained_Teachers, BOOKS, CONCRETS, TRAININGS, CURRICULUM, 
   CLASS_OBSERVATIONS, INTERVENTIONS, TESTING) VALUES (...)";
```

Se deduce que los restantes siete valores que quieres bindear son todos los `insert`...`insert6`, de manera que juntando todo, la asignación de variables debiera ser

```
$Teachers_Name              = isset($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name'] : '';
$School_Name                = isset($_POST['School_Name']) ? $_POST['School_Name'] : '';
$Implementation_Quality     = isset($_POST['Implementation_Quality']) ? $_POST['Implementation_Quality'] : '';
$Number_of_Teachers         = isset($_POST['Number_of_Teachers']) ? $_POST['Number_of_Teachers'] : '';
$Number_of_Trained_Teachers = isset($_POST['Number_of_Trained_Teachers']) ? $_POST['Number_of_Trained_Teachers'] : '';
$BOOKS                      = isset($_POST['insert']) ? $_POST['insert'] : '';
$CONCRETS                   = isset($_POST['insert1']) ? $_POST['insert1'] : '';
$TRAININGS                  = isset($_POST['insert2']) ? $_POST['insert2'] : '';
$CURRICULUM                 = isset($_POST['insert3']) ? $_POST['insert3'] : '';
$CLASS_OBSERVATIONS         = isset($_POST['insert4']) ? $_POST['insert4'] : '';
$INTERVENTIONS              = isset($_POST['insert5']) ? $_POST['insert5'] : '';
$TESTING                    = isset($_POST['insert6']) ? $_POST['insert6'] : '';
```

Ahí ya tienes tus **doce** parámetros.

Luego declaras la query con **doce** placeholders

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO other_fields(
        Teachers_Name, 
        School_Name, 
        Implementation_Quality, 
        Number_of_Teachers, 
        Number_of_Trained_Teachers, 
        BOOKS, 
        CONCRETS, 
        TRAININGS, 
        CURRICULUM, 
        CLASS_OBSERVATIONS, 
        INTERVENTIONS, 
        TESTING) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Y después del `prepare` haces el bind con las **doce** variables.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth, 'ssssssssssss',
    $Teachers_Name, // parámetro 1
    $School_Name, // parámetro 2
    $Implementation_Quality, // parámetro 3
    $Number_of_Teachers, // parámetro 4
    $Number_of_Trained_Teachers, // parámetro 5
    $BOOKS, // parametro 6
    $CONCRETS, // parametro 7
    $TRAININGS, // parametro 8
    $CURRICULUM, // parametro 9
    $CLASS_OBSERVATIONS, // parametro 10
    $INTERVENTIONS, // parametro 11
    $TESTING // parametro 12
);
```

Y con eso te debiera permitir hacer la inserción.

Comment: para las variables tan solo con hace [import_request_variable](http://php.net/manual/es/function.import-request-variables.php) tiene y quita un poco de codigo

Comment: ¿Todavía existe eso? Era de cuando se usaba `register_globals`. Pensé que ya no venía en PHP

Comment: Pues ya funciona pero se almacena en diferentes filas, los que son de tipo checkbox en una fila y los que son de texto en otra

Comment: ¿Se almacena en diferentes filas? Significa que tienes dos formularios distintos, podrías mostrar tu HTML