# ¿Por qué aparecen 2 filas al insertar desde un formulario en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Así se ve la base de datos, con 2 filas para cada inserción (una con datos, la otra sin):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aún no sé por qué está sucediendo esto, si estoy guardando todos los datos en una sola linea de código. Lo que quiero es que lo que está en elEL id->2 se almacene en la fila del id->1. En pocas palabras, que todos los datos estén en una sola fila

Mi código PHP

```
 <?php 
   $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "datos3");
     if(!$conexion){
        echo "Conexión no exitosa";
     } else {

$base= mysqli_select_db($conexion, "datos3");
    if(!$base){
        echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";
    }
}
 //LLAMAMOS LAS VARIBALES
$Teachers_Name              = isset($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? 
                                    $_POST['Teachers_Name'] : '';
$School_Name                = isset($_POST['School_Name']) ? 
                                    $_POST['School_Name'] : '';
$Implementation_Quality     = isset($_POST['Implementation_Quality']) ? 
                                    $_POST['Implementation_Quality'] : '';
$Number_of_Teachers         = isset($_POST['Number_of_Teachers']) ? 
                                    $_POST['Number_of_Teachers'] : '';
$Number_of_Trained_Teachers = isset($_POST['Number_of_Trained_Teachers']) ? 
                                    $_POST['Number_of_Trained_Teachers'] : 
                                    '';
$BOOKS                      = isset($_POST['insert']) ? $_POST['insert'] : 
                                    '';
$CONCRETS                   = isset($_POST['insert1']) ? $_POST['insert1'] : 
                                    '';
$TRAININGS                  = isset($_POST['insert2']) ? $_POST['insert2'] : 
                                    '';
$CURRICULUM                 = isset($_POST['insert3']) ? $_POST['insert3'] : 
                                    '';
$CLASS_OBSERVATIONS         = isset($_POST['insert4']) ? $_POST['insert4'] : 
                                    '';
$INTERVENTIONS              = isset($_POST['insert5']) ? $_POST['insert5'] : 
                                    '';
$TESTING                    = isset($_POST['insert6']) ? $_POST['insert6'] : 
                                    '';
//Guarda las variables


  $sql="INSERT INTO datos_3(Teachers_Name, School_Name, 
      Implementation_Quality, Number_of_Teachers, 
      Number_of_Trained_Teachers, BOOKS, CONCRETS, TRAININGS, CURRICULUM, 
      CLASS_OBSERVATIONS, INTERVENTIONS, TESTING) VALUES 
      (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

 $sth = mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'ssssssssssss', $Teachers_Name, $School_Name, 
                        $Implementation_Quality, $Number_of_Teachers, 
                        $Number_of_Trained_Teachers, 
                        $BOOKS, $CONCRETS, $TRAININGS, $CURRICULUM, 
                        $CLASS_OBSERVATIONS, $INTERVENTIONS, $TESTING);
$ejecutar = mysqli_stmt_execute($sth);

if(!$ejecutar){
 echo "Hubo algun error";
} else {

 echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='index.php'>Volver</a>";
}

?>
```

HTML Y Jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>formulario</title>
  <link rel ="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="estilos.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").add("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(){
    calcular();
  })

});

function calcular(){
  $radios = $("input[type=radio]:checked");
  $checkboxs = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  var coste_total = 0;
  $checkboxs.each(function(){
    coste_total = coste_total + parseInt($(this).val());
  })
  $radios.each(function(){
    coste_total = coste_total + parseInt($(this).val());
  })
  $(".resultado").html(coste_total)
}
</script>
<body>
  <div clas="wrap">
            <form action="insert.php" class="formulario" method="POST">
              <br>
              <p>BOOKS</p>
              <div class="checkbox">
              <br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="20" id="CourseBooks" class="get_value" style="display: none;">
                <label for="CourseBooks">CourseBooks</label>

                <input type="checkbox" value="20" id="PracticeBooks" class="get_value"  style="display: none;">
                <label for="PracticeBooks">PracticeBooks</label>
              <br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <p>CONCRETS</p>
              <div class="radio">
               <input value ="8" type="radio" id="All Suggested" class="get_value2" style="display: none;" required>
               <label for="All Suggested">All Suggested</label>

                <input value="4" type="radio" id="Some Suggested" class="get_value2"  style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="Some Suggested">Some Suggested</label>

                <input value="0" type="radio" id="None Suggested" class="get_value2" style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="None Suggested">None Suggested</label>

              <br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="text">
              <p>TEACHERS</p>
                <label for="Number of Teachers">Number of Teachers</label>
                <input type="number" name="Number_of_Teachers" id="Number_of_Teachers" placeholder="number" required>
              <br>
                <label for="Number of Trained Teachers">Number of Trained Teachers</label>
                <input type="number" name="Number_of_Trained_Teachers" id="Number_of_Trained_Teachers" placeholder="number" required>
              <br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <p>TRAININGS</p>
              <div class="radio">
                <input value="4" type="radio" class="get_value3" id="Module 1: Foundatons" style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="Module 1: Foundatons">Module 1: Foundatons</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="radio" class="get_value3" id="Module 2: Questioning" style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="Module 2: Questioning">Module 2: Questioning</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="radio" class="get_value3" id="Module 3: Smart Environments" style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="Module 3: Smart Environments">Module 3: Smart Environments</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="radio" class="get_value3" id="Module 4: Differentiation" style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="Module 4: Differentiation">Module 4: Differentiation</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="radio" class="get_value3" id="Module 5: Innovation" style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="Module 5: Innovation">Module 5: Innovation</label>
              <br>
            </div>
              <br>
              <P>CURRICULUM</P>
              <br>
              <div class="radio">
              <p>Line Up</p>
              <br>
                <input value="4" type="radio" id="90%-100%" class="get_value4"  style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="90%-100%">90% - 100%</label>
              <br>
                <input value="3" type="radio" id="80%-89%" class="get_value4" style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="80%-89%">80% - 89%</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="radio" id="70%-79%" class="get_value4" style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="70%-79%">70% - 79%</label>
              <br>
                <input value="1" type="radio" id="Less than 70%" class="get_value4" style="display: none;" required>
                <label for="Less than 70%">Less than 70%</label>
              <br>
              </div>
              <br>
              <p>CLASS OBSERVATIONS</p>
              <div class="radio">
              <br>
                <input value="1" type="radio" id="One Routine" class="get_value5" style="display: none;" >
                <label for="One Routine">One Routine</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="radio" id="Two Routines" class="get_value5" style="display: none;" >
                <label for="Two Routines">Two Routines</label>
              <br>
                <input value="3" type="radio" id="Three Routines" class="get_value5" style="display: none;">
                <label for="Three Routines">Three Routines</label>
              <br>
                <input value="4" type="radio" id="Four Routines" class="get_value5"  style="display: none;">
                <label for="Four Routines">Four Routines</label>
              <br>
                <input value="5" type="radio" id="Five Routines" class="get_value5"  style="display: none;">
                <label for="Five Routines">Five Routines</label>
              <br>
                <input value="6" type="radio" id="Six Routines" class="get_value5"  style="display: none;">
                <label for="Six Routines">Six Routines</label>
              <br>
                <input value="7" type="radio" id="Seven Routines" class="get_value5"  style="display: none;">
                <label for="Seven Routines">Seven Routines</label>
              <br>
                <input value="8" type="radio" id="Eight Routines" class="get_value5" style="display: none;">
                <label for="Eight Routines">Eight Routines</label>
              <br>
            </div>
              <br>
              <p>INTERVENTIONS</p>
              <div class="checkbox">
              <br>
                <input value="8" type="checkbox" id="Still learning Students protocolo" class="get_value6" name="checkboxs[]" style="display: none;">
                <label for="Still learning Students protocolo">Still learning Students protocolo</label>
              <br>
            </div>
              <br>
              <p>TESTING</p>
              <div class="checkbox">
              <p>Pre-post testing</p>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="One Grade"  name="checkboxs[]" class="get_value7" style="display: none;" >
                <label for="One Grade">One Grade</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="Two Grades"  name="checkboxs[]" class="get_value7"  style="display: none;">
                <label for="Two Grades">Two Grades</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="Three Grades"  name="checkboxs[]" class="get_value7" style="display: none;">
                <label for="Three Grades">Three Grades</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="Four Grades"  name="checkboxs[]" class="get_value7"  style="display: none;">
                <label for="Four Grades">Four Grades</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="Five Grades"  name="checkboxs[]" class="get_value7"  style="display: none;">
                <label for="Five Grades">Five Grades</label>
              <br>
                <input value="2" type="checkbox" id="Six Grades"  name="checkboxs[]" class="get_value7" style="display: none;">
                <label for="Six Grades">Six Grades</label>
              <br>
            </div>
              <br>
              <p style="color:#0774D9; font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Verdana' ">Implementation Quality</p>
              <p  class="resultado" style="background:#0774D9; color: #fff; font-size: 30px"></p>

              <br>

              <div class="text">

                <label for="Teachers_Name">Teacher's Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="Teachers_Name" id="Teachers_Name" placeholder="Name" required>
              <br>
              <br>
                <label for="School_Name">School Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="School_Name" id="School_Name" placeholder="School Name" required>
              <br>
              <br>
                <label for="Implementation_Quality">Write here your Implementation Quality score :</label>
                <input type="text" name="Implementation_Quality" id="Implementation_Quality" placeholder="Implementation Quality" required>

              </div>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 20px;background:#0774D9; color: #fff; font-size: 20px; border-radius: 10px; font-family: 'Verdana';padding: 5px 15px 5px 20px">

            </form>
  </div>
  <h1 id="result"></h1>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#submit').click(function(){
      var insert = [];
      var insert1 = [];
      var insert2 = [];
      var insert3 = [];
      var insert4 = [];
      var insert5 = [];
      var insert6 = [];
   $('.get_value').each(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked"))
     {
       insert.push($(this).attr("id"))
     }
   });
   insert = insert.toString();

  $('.get_value2').each(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked"))
     {
       insert1.push($(this).attr("id"))
     }
   });
   insert1 = insert1.toString();

  $('.get_value3').each(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked"))
     {
       insert2.push($(this).attr("id"))
     }
   });
   insert2 = insert2.toString();

  $('.get_value4').each(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked"))
     {
       insert3.push($(this).attr("id"))
    }
  });
  insert3 = insert3.toString();

  $('.get_value5').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
      insert4.push($(this).attr("id"))
    }
  });
  insert4 = insert4.toString();

  $('.get_value6').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
      insert5.push($(this).attr("id"))
    }
  });
  insert5 = insert5.toString();

  $('.get_value7').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
      insert6.push($(this).attr("id"))
    }
  });
  insert6 = insert6.toString();
  $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{insert:insert, insert1:insert1, insert2:insert2, insert3:insert3, insert4:insert4, insert5:insert5, insert6:insert6},
    success:function(data){
      $('#result').html(data);
    }
  });
});
});
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Sería oportuno señalar que esta pregunta es un spin-off de esta otra: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119654/c%C3%B3mo-unir-dos-c%C3%B3digos-php-en-uno-solo/119720?noredirect=1#comment222878_119720

Comment: PD: muéstranos el HTML de tu formulario

Comment: Estas haciendo dos insert. vas a tener que mostrar mas informacion para que sepamos que pasa...

Comment: Estan seguros, es que es algo largo el HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El error.** Estás enviando el formulario 2 veces:

1. Cuando se hace click en "Send", estás enviando los datos por AJAX:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#submit').click(function(){

           // ...

           $.ajax({
               url:"insert.php",
               method:"POST",
               data:{insert:insert, insert1:insert1, insert2:insert2, insert3:insert3, insert4:insert4, insert5:insert5, insert6:insert6},
               success:function(data){
                   $('#result').html(data);
               }
           });

       });
   });
   ```
2. Tu formulario envía los datos a la página que agregaste en el `action`.

   ```
   <form action="insert.php" class="formulario" method="POST">
   ```

**Cómo solucionarlo.** Al final del evento `click`, podrías agregar

```
return false;
```

para cancelar la acción por omisión del evento (o sea, que el `form` no envíe los datos).

- Esto es válido sólo para eventos en jQuery, ya que devolver `false` es lo mismo que llamar a `Event.preventDefault` y a `Event.stopPropagation`.

Quedaría:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){

            // ...

            return false;
        });
    });
```

**Por qué aparece una línea en blanco en la base de datos.** Evidentemente vas a tener que depurar un poco el evento `click` y ver por qué en tu código no se están enviando correctamente los datos, o por qué no se están recibiendo correctamente en el PHP. Sin embargo, eso te queda para descubrirlo.

Una pista: desde la llamada por AJAX estás enviando 7 valores,

```
data:{insert:insert, insert1:insert1, insert2:insert2, insert3:insert3, insert4:insert4, insert5:insert5, insert6:insert6},
```

pero en tu PHP estás guardando 12 valores en la base de datos... ¿Dónde están los 5 que faltan?

Comment: MEN TU ERES MUY MAKIO A LO BIEN! Mis respetos.